# How to set transparent background color for radiobutton?

Tags: background-color, android-radiogroup

I'm trying this, but it doesn't remove color, only removes checked radiobuttons as i wish after clicking a button. Here is the function i wrote:

```
public void przyciskReset(View view) {
        RadioGroup grupaPytanie1 = findViewById(R.id.grupa1);
        RadioGroup grupaPytanie2 = findViewById(R.id.grupa2);
        RadioGroup grupaPytanie3 = findViewById(R.id.grupa3);
        RadioGroup grupaPytanie4 = findViewById(R.id.grupa4);
        RadioGroup grupaPytanie5 = findViewById(R.id.grupa5);
        RadioGroup grupaPytanie6 = findViewById(R.id.grupa6);
        EditText prezydentImie = findViewById(R.id.p4);
        grupaPytanie1.clearCheck();
        grupaPytanie1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        grupaPytanie2.clearCheck();
        grupaPytanie2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF0000"));
        grupaPytanie3.clearCheck();
        grupaPytanie3.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
        grupaPytanie4.clearCheck();
        grupaPytanie4.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
        grupaPytanie5.clearCheck();
        grupaPytanie5.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
        grupaPytanie6.clearCheck();
        grupaPytanie6.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
        prezydentImie.setText(null);
```